# How to connect to SQL Server through firewall

Tags: sql-server, port

I have a SQL Server (clustered named instance) in our intranet and we have an application sittitng outside the intranet.

How can we setup a connection from our application to the database (port opening?).

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow.  This probably belongs on SuperUser or ServerFault.  The question also isn't answerable with the information provided; we'd need to know your infrastructure setup.  It could be as simple as port forwarding port 1435 (if that's what you use for your instance), or much more involved depending on your network infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a port opened and append the port number to the server name or IP address used in your connection string - separated with comma, this allows you to connect to SQL.